# Combine two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
```

Using this list of dictionaries,
how can i combine same keys?

```
[{"APPLE": ["RED","GREEN"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}]
```

I want to get this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve the `list` in desired format via creating intermediate dictionary to store the mapping *(even better to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict))* as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in my_list:
    for k, v in item.items():
        temp_dict[k] += v

# content of `temp_dict` is:
#     {
#          'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN'], 
#          'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']
#     }
```

For converting the `dict` to the list of desired format, you may use a *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> new_list = [{k: v} for k, v in temp_dict.items()]
>>> new_list
[{'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN']}, {'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Without importing any modules,

```
a = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
temp = {}
for i in a:
    for key in i:
        if key in temp.keys():
            temp[key].extend(i[key])
        else:
            temp[key] = i[key]
# print(temp)
op = [{key:val} for key,val in temp.items()]
print(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Simply iterate through each dictionary in your list and then add the key and all values, if a key has already been added then it will just extend the list with the other values.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]

temp = OrderedDict() # use ordered dict if you want to maintain order
# collapse dicts from data
for d in data:
    for key in d:
        temp.setdefault(key, []).extend(d[key])

res = [ { k : v } for k, v in temp.items() ] # split back into individual dicts
print(res)

# Output
[{'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN']}, {'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']}]
```

Comment: That's good.. Still if you could change the output into a list instead of dict.! I guess that's what she's asking for

Comment: Oh mis-read it. Will fix in a sec. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need easily readable code, you may use:

```
data = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]

keys = {key for keylist in [item.keys() for item in data] for key in keylist}
temp = {k: [color for item in data if k in item.keys() for color in item[k]] for k in keys}
rslt = [{k: v} for k, v in temp.items()]
print(rslt)

>>> [{'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN']}, {'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']}]
```

**Hint:** *Don't take this too serious. I was just curious about doing as much inline as possible. You could even go further and nest the comprehensions into another...*

```
rslt = [{k: v} for k, v in {k: [color for item in data if k in item.keys() for color in item[k]] for k in {key for keylist in [item.keys() for item in data] for key in keylist}}.items()]
```

*Just for the case you want to make sure that nobody, including you, can follow this code after a while... ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other suggested solutions but using reduce() function.

Define a helper to merge dictionaries and use it in reduce() function

```
def ext(d1, d2):
  for k, v in d2.items():
    d1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
  return d1

src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
dst = reduce(ext, src, {})
print dst
>>> {'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN'], 'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']}
```

Now you have a succinct data structure: a dictionary and you can do different queries on it. To get the desired output:

```
print [ { k : v } for k, v in dst.items() ]
[{'APPLE': ['RED', 'GREEN']}, {'BANANA': ['YELLOW', 'GREEN']}]
```

---

### Out of curiosity run performance tests of listed solutions

**Simplicity wins ([Natarajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6582814/natarajan)), obscurity fails behind ([jbndir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5677602/jbndlr)) (due to additional temporary copies).**

*Dictionary `setdefault()` function doesn't change the performance noticeably, it shortens code, so should be used instead of `if else` statement.*

```
import timeit
from collections import defaultdict

def f0():
  src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
  dst = defaultdict(list)
  for item in src:
      for k, v in item.items():
          dst[k] += v

def ext(d1, d2):
  for k, v in d2.items():
    d1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
  return d1

def f1():
  src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
  dst = reduce(ext, src, {})

def f2():
  src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
  dst = {}
  for i in src:
    for key in i:
      if key in dst.keys():
        dst[key].extend(i[key])
      else:
        dst[key] = i[key]

def f3():
  src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
  dst = {}
  for i in src:
    for key in i:
      dst.setdefault(key, []).extend(i[key])

def f4():
  src = [{"APPLE": ["RED"]}, {"BANANA": ["YELLOW", "GREEN"]}, {"APPLE": ["GREEN"]}]
  keys = {key for keylist in [item.keys() for item in src] for key in keylist}
  temp = {k: [color for item in src if k in item.keys() for color in item[k]] for k in keys}


min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f0())):  4.64622211456
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f1())):  4.51267290115
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f2())):  3.18728780746
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f3())):  3.35215997696
min(timeit.repeat(lambda: f4())):  6.80625200272
```