# Combining multiple lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several lists of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains a unique `id` value that is common among all lists. I'd like to combine them into a single list of dicts, where each dict is joined on that `id` value.

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

desired_output = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}]
```

I tried doing something like the answer found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018660/7564393, but I'm getting very confused since I have more than 2 lists. Should I try using a `defaultdict` approach? More importantly, I am NOT always going to know the other values, only that the `id` value is present in all dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

desired_output = []
for _, values in groupby(sorted([*list1, *list2, *list3], key=lambda x: x['id']), key=lambda x: x['id']):
    temp = {}
    for d in values:
        temp.update(d)
    desired_output.append(temp)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first build a dict of dicts, then turn it into a list:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

dict_out = defaultdict(dict)

for d in chain(list1, list2, list3):
    dict_out[d['id']].update(d)
out = list(dict_out.values())

print(out)
# [{'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}]
```

`itertools.chain` allows you to iterate on all the dicts contained in the 3 lists. We build a dict `dict_out` having the id as key, and the corresponding dict being built as value. This way, we can easily `update` the already built part with the small dict of our current iteration.

Comment: `out = list(d.values())` should be enough, you don't need list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

# combine all lists
d = {} # id -> dict
for l in [list1, list2, list3]:
    for list_d in l:
        if 'id' not in list_d: continue
        id = list_d['id']
        if id not in d:
            d[id] = list_d
        else:
            d[id].update(list_d)

# dicts with same id are grouped together since id is used as key
res = [v for v in d.values()]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have presented a functional approach without using **itertools** (which is excellent in rapid development work).

This solution will work for any number of lists as the function takes variable number of arguments and also let user to specify the type of return output (list/dict).

By default it returns list as you want that otherwise it returns dictionary in case if you pass `as_list = False`.

> I preferred dictionary to solve this because its fast and search complexity is also less.

Just have a look at the below `get_packed_list()` function.

#### `get_packed_list()`

```
def get_packed_list(*dicts_lists, as_list=True):
    output = {}

    for dicts_list in dicts_lists:
        for dictionary in dicts_list:
            _id = dictionary.pop("id") # id() is in-built function so preferred _id

            if _id not in output:
                # Create new id
                output[_id] = {"id": _id}

            for key in dictionary:
                output[_id][key] = dictionary[key]

            dictionary["id"] = _id # push back the 'id' after work (call by reference mechanism)

    if as_list:
        return [output[key] for key in output]

    return output # dictionary
```

#### `Test`

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]


output = get_packed_list(list1, list2, list3)
print(output) 
# [{'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}]

output = get_packed_list(list1, list2, list3, as_list=False)
print(output)
# {1: {'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, 2: {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

print(list1+list2+list3)
```

Comment: The answer does not produce the desired output

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

```py
list1 = [{'id': 1, 'value': 20}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'sum': 10}, {'id': 2, 'sum': 11}]
list3 = [{'id': 1, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'total': 32}]

result = []
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
      final_dict = dict(list(list1[i].items()) + list(list2[i].items()) + list(list3[i].items()))
      result.append(final_dict)

print(result)
```

output : [{'id': 1, 'value': 20, 'sum': 10, 'total': 30}, {'id': 2, 'value': 21, 'sum': 11, 'total': 32}]